# Why flushMicrotasks() and tick() does not executes setImmediate callback in fakeAsync?

Tags: angular, typescript

Following test fulfills all expectations

```
  it('flushing works.....', fakeAsync(() => {
    let timeoutFlag = false;
    let immediateFlag = false;
    setTimeout(() => timeoutFlag = true);
    setImmediate(() => immediateFlag = true);

    expect(timeoutFlag).toBeFalsy();
    expect(immediateFlag).toBeFalsy();

    flushMicrotasks(); // #1 - why this does not executes both handlers
    expect(timeoutFlag).toBeFalsy();
    expect(immediateFlag).toBeFalsy();

    tick();
    expect(timeoutFlag).toBeTruthy();
    expect(immediateFlag).toBeFalsy();

    tick(100); // #2 - why setImmediate is never flushed?
    expect(timeoutFlag).toBeTruthy();
    expect(immediateFlag).toBeFalsy();
  }));
```

My question are

1. Why `flushMicrotasks` at #1 does not invoke both handlers?
2. Why `tick()`  affects only `setTimeout` and not `setImmediate`?
3. How to force execution of callbacks scheduled using `setImmediate ?

Comment: `setImmediate` is supported only in IE. The other mainstream browsers refused to implement. So this might be the reason it has no implementation.

Comment: how about not working `flushMicrotasks` ??

Comment: I thought `setTimeout` creates macrotasks not microtasks.

Comment: I see, I didn't knew that there is such thing ;)

Comment: [This](https://javascript.info/event-loop) article might help.